# ASP.NET MVC Regex validation with Unicode is not supported on client side validation

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, validationattribute

I want to validate a given string that will be used to save the file with the required name in the server.

this requires me to use the following REGEX:`^[\p\w\-. ]+$`
which works great but only for English strings.

so I have modified it like this `^[\p{L}\w\-. ]+$` the `{L}` modifier is set to accept any Unicode character.

this is the view-model.

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(FilesRepositoryStrings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EnterTheNamePlease")]
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(FilesRepositoryStrings), Name = "FileNameInputLabel")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[\p{L}\w\-. ]+$", ErrorMessage = @"The file name can only contain letters, numbers and characters -_.")]
public string FileName { get; set; }
```

this is the html render

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true"
data-val-regex="The file name can only contain letters, numbers and characters -_." 
data-val-regex-pattern="^[\p{L}\w\-. ]+$" 
data-val-required="הזן את השם בבקשה" 
id="UploadFileModel_FileName" 
name="UploadFileModel.FileName" 
onkeyup="$('#EnterTheNamePlease').attr('hidden', true);" 
type="text" value="" 
aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

but the client-side validation is not accepting any Unicode (Hebrew) strings..

any ways to overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can activate Unicode support in Javascript RegExp with the [/u flag](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex). It is part of ECMAScript6 but according to [this table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#RegExp_y_and_u_flags) it is not supported yet in the major browsers.

It is hacky but what you could do is to replace the client side validation with a custom regular expression engine like [XRegexp](http://xregexp.com/). It is supporting [unicode characters](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/README.md#unicode). In their example they use shorthand notation `\pL` but `\p{L}` is also supported (according to [this, chapter Unicode Categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)).

I haven't entirely tested and it might have side effects. But I think what you can do is to replace the RegExp matching in file jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

```
match = new RegExp(params).exec(value);
return (match && (match.index === 0) && (match[0].length === value.length));
```

by

```
var unicodeWord = XRegExp(params);
return unicodeWord.test(value);
```

You need to include these files to make it work:

```
<script src="src/xregexp.js"></script>
<script src="src/addons/unicode-base.js"></script>
<script src="src/addons/unicode-categories.js"></script>
<script src="src/addons/unicode-scripts.js"></script>
```

Of course it will be difficult to maintain when jquery validate evolves but it could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer-
XRegExp.js used for node.js, to use in ASP.NET MVC you need XRegExp version that operates as a pure java script, without model, I found it here:

https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Utilities/xregexp.asp

Code has an open source license.
I tried this code and solution from the answer and everything works fine...

Comment: You should comment the "previous answer" rather than create a new answer for additional information about it.

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow and had not permission to post  comments.